# Html5 auto converter?

Tags: php, javascript, html, video

I'm working on a php backend for upload videos and wondering if there is a way to convert from some of the 3 common formats to another. The idea is to simplify the upload to just one video and my app will convert it to the 3 formats to maintain compatibility.

A plugin or something?

Comment: flv m4a ogg? these ones?

Comment: ogg webm mpg, but if another format does the job, its ok.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably ffMPEG: ffmpeg.org/

There is a "plug-in" (i.e. extension) for PHP called php_ffmpeg but I strongly advise you not to use it. Just run command line instead as it's simple once you've done the first one.

Important: the conversion takes time, so make sure you have a queuing solution - line the conversions up and do one at a time (or two at a time if you have dual core CPUs, 4 for quad etc, and specify the CPU to run on).